# How does the LeaverBuster system work?

Tags: league-of-legends

Recently, I've gotten into low-priority queue for leaving around 2-3 matches in a row due to internet unstability.

I would like to ask, how does the LeaverBuster system exactly work? According to the wiki, it is determined by the percentage of the number of matches that you leave, not the number, but I would like to ask what is the threshold where you will get low priority?
Also, I've heard that if you leave too many matches, you can get temporarily or permanently banned. At what stage of time do we get banned, and if I get permanently banned, is it possible to get unbanned?
Another question is, if you get reported by other players too much, can you get banned, or muted in the chat or whatsoever? What is the penalty for getting reported too much?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Recently, I've gotten into low-priority queue for leaving around 2-3 matches in a row due to internet instability.

Too bad. Fix your internet. Those guys aren't going to let you go even when your internet is bad.

> What is the threshold where you will get low priority?

Quote from NA LoL:
The first time a player leaves a game, they’ll see a pop-up explaining that leaving is not okay and then have to manually agree to not leave future games. If they continue to ruin other players’ experiences, they’ll enter lower-priority matchmaking for a number of games.

Basically it means that when you see a pop-up after a game saying that you have to agree that you won't leave anymore games, that's the threshold. That is the last warning. From my experience, not more that 5 games.

> I've heard that if you leave too many matches, you can get temporarily or permanently banned.

Yes. True.

> At what stage of time do we get banned?

Depends on your frequency of getting banned. The chances are much higher when you get banned, for example, 6 times in a very short time (6 bans in 12 games), than being banned in a long time (6 times in 120 games).

> If I get permanently banned, is it possible to get unbanned?

No.

> if you get reported by other players too much, can you get banned, or muted in the chat or whatsoever?

Yes. You will be reported every time you break a rule and you **can** (not **will**) be punished. The effect of the ban can vary, depending on the severity.

> What is the penalty for getting reported too much?

You will get chat restricted if people reports you for being toxic numerous times.

Comment: Is there any percentage of left games where you will get banned?

Comment: Just dont leave games, then you dont have to worry about it :)

Comment: FYI the percentage of left games for a ban/exile to low priority queue is left unstated (by Riot) _on purpose_. They don't want people trying to 'game' the leaver buster system somehow.

Comment: From my experiences... If you leave too many games in a row you get a leaver buster. However if you leave games periodically say one or two games every week depending on the number of games you play you will get a warning and if you continue you get banned. ( I've been banned a lot, and not because of my internet issues well some were but it was mostly because of not really wanting to spend 10 to 20 minutes with a team thats quite literary feeding intentionally

Comment: Oh ok... I was asking because I sometimes play using mobile data, and when connection is bad, it disconnects and I have trouble reconnecting so I have no choice but to leave the game. Thanks for your help, I will keep your advices in mind :)

Comment: This answer is wrong and being up voted for the wrong reasons.  Riot has not given specific information on what causes leave buster to trigger.  They have also stated that network drops should not trigger leave buster (mind I oppose this).

Comment: @nick Let's Google this, shall we? A lot of these answers have support from the LoL community and even from staffs. Some of them are from everyone's experience and some are from common sense.

Comment: `You will get chat restricted if people reports you for being toxic numerous times.` if you are restricted and can't write/talk in any way, then you will get reported for refusing communication

Answer (score 0):

You could also stick to custom games, or P-V-AI games, The LeaverBuster doesnt cover those matches.

So if your internet is unstable, or you're sched is erratic, avoid normal and ranked games for a while.

Comment: Co-op vs bots also? I got banned for leaving one of those...